# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in Ipython console, but not externally

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Executing:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ 0.815,  0.02 , -0.053])
" ".join(map(str, x))
```

in the IPython console gives me the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

But, when I execute this on a external system terminal, it works fine!

Comment: Have you used or assigned the name `str` anywhere else in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made either `str` or `map` a string:

```
>>> map = 'some string'
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> " ".join(map(str, x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> del map
>>> str = 'some string'
>>> " ".join(map(str, x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The error message tells you what type of object you tried to apply the `(...)` call syntax to; it is not the name used in the call expression.

In the interactive session, simply delete the name and the built-in type will re-emerge:

```
>>> str = 'some string'
>>> str
'some string'
>>> del str
>>> str
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Curious, why does Python 'blame' `str` if it's `map` that's overwritten?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: because the *type* of the object you are trying to call is `str`. The *name* of the object doesn't play here and is just a coincidence.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: if you did `foo = 'some string'` then tried to call `foo`, Python would still tell you you cannot call an object of type `'str'`.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: if you instead used `foo = (1, 2)` the exception would tell you an object of type `'tuple'` is not callable.

Comment: Ack, you're right! False connections throwing me off. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Thanks! 
It was  `str`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't overwrite `str` builtin function:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array([ 0.815,  0.02 , -0.053])

In [3]: " ".join(map(str, x))
Out[3]: '0.815 0.02 -0.053'
```

---

```
In [4]: str = ''  # <--- overwrite `str`

In [5]: " ".join(map(str, x))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-69d3e83718e2> in <module>()
----> 1 " ".join(map(str, x))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```